# `Reduce` is running forever

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, inequalities

I'm trying to solve the last inequality in `Reduce` in the code below in terms of `rmax` under the parameter conditions included in `Reduce`.

```
Reduce[
  lm > 1 + theta + lm theta u && 
  lm > (-iE + rmax + iE theta + rmax theta + iD u - rmax u - iD theta u - rmax theta u)/(-iE + rmax + iD u - rmax u + iE theta u - rmax theta u - iD theta u^2 + rmax theta u^2) && 
  0 < u && 
  u < (-iE + rmax)/(-iD + rmax) && 
  (-iE + (-2 + lm) rmax)/(-1 + lm) + (lm (iD - rmax) u)/(-1 + lm) + (2 rmax (-1 + theta))/(1 - theta + lm (-1 + theta u)) > iE && 
  iH > iE && 
  iH > iD && 
  0 < theta && 
  theta < 1 && 
  lm > 1 && 
  rmax > 0 && 
  iD > 0 && 
  rmax > iD && 
  rmax > iE && 
  iE > iD && 
  (1/((1 - theta + lm (-1 + theta u))^2)) 2 (iH (-1 + lm) (-1 + theta) (1 - theta + lm (-1 + theta u)) + theta (-iE (-1 + lm + theta) + iE lm theta u + lm rmax (-1 + u) (1 - lm + theta + lm theta u))) > (1 + (2 theta)/(1 - lm - theta + lm theta u)) iE, 
rmax]
```

The code is running forever without producing any output.

Comment: iE makes no sense.  Try i E.

Comment: 1.You are for a while on this forum and still asking questions which are poorly worked out.  2. I have answerd at least one of your quetions and there wasn't information whether it was helpful or not. It doesn't encourage to answer another question

Comment: @Artes almost a decade is a minute more than a while...

Answer (score 3):

Making use of quantifiers, the following can be done.

```
Resolve[Exists[{iD, iE, iH, lm, theta, u}, lm > 1 + theta + lm theta u && 
   lm > (-iE + rmax + iE theta + rmax theta + iD u - rmax u - 
   iD theta u - rmax theta u)/(-iE + rmax + iD u - rmax u + 
   iE theta u - rmax theta u - iD theta u^2 + rmax theta u^2) && 
   0 < u &&  u < (-iE + rmax)/(-iD + 
   rmax) && (-iE + (-2 + lm) rmax)/(-1 + 
    lm) + (lm (iD - rmax) u)/(-1 + 
    lm) + (2 rmax (-1 + theta))/(1 - theta + lm (-1 + theta u)) > 
iE && iH > iE && iH > iD && 0 < theta && theta < 1 && lm > 1 && 
rmax > 0 && iD > 0 && rmax > iD && rmax > iE && iE > iD && (1/((1 - theta + lm (-1 + theta u))^2)) 2 (iH (-1 + 
      lm) (-1 + theta) (1 - theta + lm (-1 + theta u)) + 
   theta (-iE (-1 + lm + theta) + iE lm theta u + 
      lm rmax (-1 + u) (1 - lm + theta + 
         lm theta u))) > (1 + (2 theta)/(1 - lm - theta + 
      lm theta u)) iE], Reals]
```

> `-rmax < 0`

The above means each positive value of `rmax` satisfies the system of the inequalities under consideration.

Addition. Here is the verification.

```
Resolve[Implies[rmax > 0, Exists[{iD, iE, iH, lm, theta, u}, 
   lm > 1 + theta + lm theta u && 
lm > (-iE + rmax + iE theta + rmax theta + iD u - rmax u - 
    iD theta u - rmax theta u)/(-iE + rmax + iD u - rmax u + 
    iE theta u - rmax theta u - iD theta u^2 + rmax theta u^2) && 
0 < u && 
u < (-iE + rmax)/(-iD + 
    rmax) && (-iE + (-2 + lm) rmax)/(-1 + 
     lm) + (lm (iD - rmax) u)/(-1 + 
     lm) + (2 rmax (-1 + theta))/(1 - theta + lm (-1 + theta u)) >
  iE && iH > iE && iH > iD && 0 < theta && theta < 1 && lm > 1 && 
rmax > 0 && iD > 0 && rmax > iD && rmax > iE && 
iE > iD && (1/((1 - theta + lm (-1 + theta u))^2)) 2 (iH (-1 + 
       lm) (-1 + theta) (1 - theta + lm (-1 + theta u)) + 
    theta (-iE (-1 + lm + theta) + iE lm theta u + 
       lm rmax (-1 + u) (1 - lm + theta + 
          lm theta u))) > (1 + (2 theta)/(1 - lm - theta + 
       lm theta u)) iE]], Reals]
```

> `True`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Designate the sixteen inequalities given in the question as ineq.  The corresponding variables are

```
Variables[List @@ (List @@@ ineq)]
(* {iD, iE, iH, lm, rmax, theta, u} *)
```

Suppose that we want `rmax` to be as unconstrained as possible.  Then, applying `Reduce` to the first fifteen inequalities with the variables ordered as shown yields

```
s1 = List @@ Reduce[(List @@ ineq)[[;; 15]], {rmax, iD, iE, iH, theta, u, lm}]
(* {rmax > 0, 0 < iD < rmax, iD < iE < rmax, iH > iE, 0 < theta < 1, 
    0 < u < (-iE + rmax)/(-iD + rmax), 
    lm > (-iE + rmax + iE theta + rmax theta + iD u - rmax u - 
    iD theta u - rmax theta u)/(-iE + rmax + iD u - rmax u + 
    iE theta u - rmax theta u - iD theta u^2 + rmax theta u^2)} *)
```

With the sixteenth equation included, `Reduce` does not yield an answer in a reasonable time.  So, instead try

```
FindInstance[ineq[[;; 15]], {rmax, iD, iE, iH, theta, u, lm}, 100000];
Count[Replace[ineq[[16]], %, All], True]
(* 100000 *)
```

In other words, the sixteenth inequality apparently always is satisfied for the solution `s1` above.  (Incidentally, `s1` includes only nine inequalities, indicating that six inequalities in `ineq[[;;15]]` are redundant.)

Suppose, instead, that we want `rmax` to be as constrained as possible by the other six variables.  Then, applying `Reduce` to the first fifteen equations with the variables appropriately reordered yields

```
s2 = List @@ Reduce[(List @@ ineq)[[;; 15]], {iD, iE, iH, theta, u, lm, rmax}]
(* {iD > 0, iE > iD, iH > iE, 0 < theta < 1, 0 < u < 1, 
   lm > (-1 - theta)/(-1 + theta u), 
   rmax > (-iE + iE lm + iE theta + iD u - iD lm u - iD theta u - 
   iE lm theta u + iD lm theta u^2)/(-1 + lm - theta + u - lm u + 
   theta u - lm theta u + lm theta u^2)} *)
```

Again, we take account of the sixteenth inequality by

```
FindInstance[ineq[[;; 15]], {iD, iE, iH, theta, u, lm, rmax}, 100000];
Count[Replace[ineq[[16]], %, All], True]
(* 100000 *)
```

Not surprisingly, here too the sixteenth inequality appears to be redundant.  Incidentally, applying `s2` to the sixteenth inequality simplifies it but only modestly.

```
Simplify[ineq[[16]], s2]
(* 2 iH (-1 + lm) (-1 + theta) (1 - theta + lm (-1 + theta u)) + 
   2 lm rmax theta (-1 + u) (1 + theta + lm (-1 + theta u)) > 
   iE (1 - theta + lm (-1 + theta u))^2 *)
```

In summary, the system of sixteen inequalities in the question can be reduced to nine inequalities, which can be satisfied by an infinity of solutions.  These solutions can be arranged so that `rmax` can be minimally or maximally constrained, and options in-between.